# How to approximate line segments in a grayscale image?

Tags: c, opencv

did any one know how to approximate lines from grayscale image resulted from line segment detector: using opencv or C language! in the image attached you see that each finger composed of many lines, what i need to do is to make each finger consists of exactly two parallel lines (i.e. approximate small lines to fit into only one line), if any one helps me, i will appreciate that.
N.B. i'm new to stackocerflow therefore i'm not allowed to post images, so for more clarification, that's the link of the image.

http://www.2shared.com/photo/Ff7mFtV3/Optimal.html

grayscale image resulted from line segment detector (LSD)

Comment: dear Karlphillip, for more clarification, what i want to do is to get each finger consists of two straight lines (e.g like the railway lines) the image in the link below contains two rays, one points to a straight line and labeled by a circle, the other points to a non straight line and labeled by a rectangle, i want two have all the finger lines like straight line pointed to by the ray which is labeled by a circle,thanks in advance.   http://www.2shared.com/photo/jf2xNbIz/DISTANCE_ONLY.html

Comment: i wonder why was your answer canceled ??

Comment: I deleted it since it has nothing to do with your question. I understand what you're trying to do but I don't have any ideas right now. When I do, I'll come back and let you know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What have you done so far? You might need some heuristics. First add all segments on a table, try calculating the inclination of each of the segments and then sorting them by this as index. Afterwards, consider all segments that have an inclination say close by 5% or something to have the exact same inclination. This will induce a partitioning in the table. You might want to draw them using different colors so that you find the perfect parameter value.

Now you need to 'merge' all segments that have the same inclination and are close together. I'd try to measure the distance between the segments (google an algorithm for that) and sort the segments of each partition according to this. Consider merging segments that are close by less than, for instance, 3% of the total image height in pixels or something (find that empirically).

Last step, merging the segments should be very easy compared to the rest.

If you really want to find the fingers, you can stop earlier and compare the groups of same inclination to check if there are two *almost* (by 7% or so) parallel. The 5 closest pairs of inclinations should be fingers :-)

Comment: Thanks Giovanni for your concern, i'll try that later.